# Converting Images into video and broadcasting that video

Tags: java, javascript, image, video-streaming

we are designing screen-casting system we found out one library in javascript html2canvas which can provide us image of webpage.now i also the idea of how to convert that series of image into video. now we want to broadcast this video  and we want to do this process as live so that user can feels that he is getting real time video from the other user kind of team viewer or skype does.

1. Now first things is it possible to go by this solution and if than what is best possible way to create video and broadcast it.
2. does anybody have another solution for it

thank you

Comment: 2ggrigery i know that java != javascript. i don't know why you have commented this way well thank you but i know that both are different language javascript was developed by Brendan Eich of Netscape and java by james gosling team of sun micro-system